# Why Alert appears everytime i enter in to the page?

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have alert in homepage that welcomes new user after sign up/in, but everytime when i come back to homepage again it shows me alert .

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.run(() => showAlert(context: context));
  }

  void showAlert({required BuildContext context}) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
          child: CustomAnnounceCard(
            title: '⚙️ Welcome to Beta test',
            positiveTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[Here you can see alert by itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VraWt.png)

Guys, help me to make it one-time alert, so new users can only see it after sign in/up

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to solve this problem , I will give you the easiest .
Declare a `bool` in the class `StatefullWidget` name it **isNew** and make it nullable by adding `?` after **bool** like this `bool? isNew;` .
then make a constructor of the **bool** that you declared , after that replace your function `initState()` with this bellow :

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if(widget.isNew)Timer.run(() => showAlert(context: context));
  }
```

then go to your Signup page and in the navigation function add inside homepage class `isNew: true` like the code bellow :

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(isNew: true)));
```

Comment: This is not an ideal solution, as it will always when running the app show alert because `isNew` bool will be instantiated every time the app is started. You should persist `isNew` value to shared_preferences or any other persistent storage mechanism.

Comment: As I said above is the easiest , I know is not ideal but considering that he still learning , I gave him a simple solution .